# How to use the terminal in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api

I'm trying to integrate Google Sign-in into my app, and I'm following this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating). However, I'm trying to add the configuration file to my project, and the tutorial says that I should use this command:

`$ move path-to-download/google-services.json app/`

When I open the terminal in Android Studio and write the command it says:

`'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

I've also noticed that it's similar to Command prompt (I'm using Windows). Can I just copy the .json file and paste it in my app folder?

Comment: Yes.You can just copy it.$ is not need to type.$ means in terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe $ (dollar sign) is indicating a start of new line in Unix based OS terminal. In Windows OS, the command should be

```
MOVE [Source] [Target]
```

For more information, [check this link.](http://ss64.com/nt/move.html)

Or you can just copy and paste it in your app folder. That will be suffice as well as.

Answer (score 0):

'$' is the user prompt, You should omit the '$' and the command should work

Comment: I write `C:/Users/Hud/Desktop /google-services.json app/` but it says 
`The syntax of the command is incorrect`

Comment: Was writing `move C:/Users/Hud/Desktop /google-services.json app/`

Comment: you have a space between C:/Users/Hud/Desktop and /google-services.json